# Use a promise result from a fetch-api in an if statement of another function - JS

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

**So I have this fetch-api**

```
let test = () => fetch(usd_api).then(response => response.json())
.then(data => data.exchange_rates.dash_usd);
```

**Console log**

```
let console_test = () => {console.log(test())}
```

[image]

How can use this number `[[PromiseResult]]: 134.445...` in the following function where the number **150** is.

```
function main(){

         fetch(txs_api).then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
                
             var amount = data.txs[0].vout[1].value;
               
             if(amount == 150){
                // SUCCESS!
                $('#modal').modal('hide');
                console.log('requests stopped');
                clearInterval(interval);
             }
         })
}
```

Comment: @TusharShahi it gives me an error `test2:62 Uncaught ReferenceError: console_test is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

Comment: `fetch` already returns a promise, wrapper promise constructor is not needed.

Comment: Use `async function console_test () {console.log(await test())}`

Comment: @Yousaf yes thanks

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to make two parallel API calls and get both numeric values in an array: `Promise.all([fetch(...), fetch(...)]).then(...)`

Comment: What does `test` have to do with `comfirm_transaction`? The latter seems to work, no?

Comment: @Bergi I need to work with the number that `test()` returns inside the `confirmation_transaction` function, where the if statement is.

Comment: @Gass In that case, you'll want to do `.then(function(data) { return test.then(function(exchangeRate) { … }); })`

Comment: @Bergi could you please make this comment a detailed answer. I'm new to fetch and promises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @FZs Nope .. I tried but I had to many problems trying to understand it and apply it to my code, that's why I asked... But I figured it out with the help of everyone in this question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Don't know if it's the best way to do it but it's working.

```
function main(){

  fetch(usd_api).then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
                        
      var dash_price = data.exchange_rates.dash_usd;
                    
      fetch(txs_api).then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
                    
          var amount = data.txs[0].vout[1].value;

          if(amount == dash_price){
              // SUCCESS!
              $('#modal').modal('hide');
              console.log('requests stopped');
              clearInterval(interval);
          }
      })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let test = () => fetch(usd_api)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data.exchange_rates.dash_usd);
```

You want too keep using the same promise, if you want to log the result of your promise you need to wait for it to be completed:

```js
// with .then()
test().then(console.log);

// or with await if you can:
console.log(await test());
```

Comment: I think you need `test().then(console.log);`

Comment: @AlphaHowl Oh yeah, absolutly

Comment: Okay, that's cool but how can I do the if statement in `confirm_transaction` function using the `test()` returned value?

Comment: By the way this didn't work I don't know why `console.log(await test());`

Answer (score -1):

Do not return value.
Because it returns to below function

```
function(data) {
  return data.exchange_rates.dash_usd
}
```

If you want to return your value to a variable you have to use **Promise** like below.

```
    let test = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(usd_api).then(response => response.json())
            .then(function (data) {
                resolve(data.exchange_rates.dash_usd) 
            });
    })
    
    async function demo(){
        let console_test  = await test
        console.log(console_test )
    }
    demo()
```

> ***Note*** : Do not forget to use **async** and **await**

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: @Bergi. This is for demo. If you are not using fetch. You are simply using any calculation which take time. You can use promise.

Comment: The OP already uses promises and `fetch`. Their code for `test` is working. You should not use `new Promise`.